# ArgumentError: Factory not registered - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

As I found this is a very common problem, but I still can not solve it.

I create a user factory (I use Devise), in spec/factories/users.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "Jonas"
    last_name "Sniegas"
    email "test@test.com"
    password "asdfasdf"
    password_confirmation "asdfasdf"
  end
end
```

And try to create it from test console ( `rails c -e test` ):

`FactoryGirl.create(:user)`

And then:

> ArgumentError: Factory not registered: user   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in
>   `find'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in`
>   method_missing'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:85:in
>   `factory_by_name'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:12:in`run'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'   from (irb):1   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in`
>   start'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in`
>   console'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in
>   `run_command!'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`
>   '   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`block in require'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`require'   from /Users/user/Desktop/Ruby/Test/bin/rails:9:in `<top
>   (required)>'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in`load'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in`load_dependency'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'   from
>   /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'

  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
```

I also tried to add `FactoryGirl.find_definitions` in the `before do` block in spec/rails_helper.rb and specify all factories in one file - spec/factories.rb. Nothing seems to work..

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with Spring... Had to stop it - `spring stop`.

Now everything works well. I will leave this answer since in those many many questions and answers I went through, no-one suggested to stop preloader...

Comment: When running rspec from the command line, you can also add in `DISABLE_SPRING=true` along with `bundle exec rspec` to surpress it from firing up again.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to add "When weird things are happening, restart spring" to very early in your troubleshooting process.

Comment: Same issue with zeus over here.